# Access parent component from MenuItem command callback

Tags: angular, menuitem, primeng

I'm using **PrimeNG 5.2** in an **Angular 5** application.

I'm trying to display a list of product when the user clicks on a item of a menu.

To do so, I have a `PanelMenu` where the first level of items contain the main categories of products and the second level contain the subcategories. In the second level, each subcategory has an associated `click event`, in which I need to put some logic (fetch products by category, show table etc.).

Here is the working code I have so far :

```js
(...)
// Populate second level items with subcategories
categories.forEach(cat =>
{
    if(cat['parent'] == category['id']) // 'category' is the first level category
    {
        subcats.push({
            label: cat['description'],
            id: cat['id'],
            command: this.subCatClick
        });
    }
});
items.push({label: category['description'], items: subcats});  // Items of the menu
```

```js
subCatClick(event)
{
    //this.logger.log(`clicked on cat ${event.item.label}`, false);
    //this.getProductByCategoryId(event.item.id);

    // 'this' refers to the item here !
    console.log(this);
}
```

As mentioned by the comment, `this` refers to the `MenuItem` (here a subcategory) and thus doesn't contain any reference to the functions / services I want to call (commented in the above example).

Those functions / services are members of the `component` that contains the `PanelMenu`. How can I access them from the `click event` ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rewrite the line where you pass the function reference:

```
command: this.subCatClick
```

to arrow function syntax, which will bind 'this' to the 'this' of the callee:

```
command: (event) => this.subCatClick(event)
```

alternatively you can use the *.bind* keyword of javascript:

```
command: this.subCatClick.bind(this)
```